# Best database search implementation for bootstrap?

Tags: search, bootstrap

I've seen a lot of talk about **jQuery** bootgrid for database search with bootstrap. I've also seen a bunch of site just using plain old php query search for databases with bootstrap.

Is there a *better* way to do this? (Either one or the other -or- even a completely different way?)

Does bootstrap have some native way to do this itself?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question that's primarily focused on a content management system, databases and programming. See: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic